# SQL Server Date comparison throws error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help on this, how independent query works but comparison is failing for below code,I am trying to compare only dates not time so tried the query like this.

```
SELECT CAST(getdate() AS DATE)---'2/9/2017 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE)----'1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT CAST(getdate() AS DATE) > CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE); -- Error SQLSTATE 42000
```

Comment: There's no boolean data type in SQL Server - so you can't have the result of a comparison operation as an expression in a result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this condition into context. For instance like this

```
SELECT case when CAST(getdate() AS DATE) > CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE) 
            then 1 
            else 0 
       end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try DATEDIFF() to find out difference between 2 dates.

select DATEDIFF( DAY,(CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE)) ,(CAST(getdate() AS DATE)))

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @nowDate DATE
SELECT @nowDate = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)

DECLARE @otherDate DATE
SELECT @otherDate = CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE)

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @nowDate, @otherDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(getdate() AS DATE)---'2/9/2017 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE)----'1/15/2017 12:00:00 AM'
SELECT IIF(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) > CAST('2017/01/15' AS DATE),1,0); --good,  you must use iif (or case when ) for predicates
```

Comment: IIF only exists in SQL Server 2012 or later. If using an older version, you will have to use a CASE statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare in `SELECT`, you can use below code to determinate if date is greater or not than current date, or it is today.

```
DECLARE @DATE NVARCHAR(20) = '2017/01/15' 

IF (CAST(getdate() AS DATE) > CAST(@DATE AS DATE))
    PRINT 'Selected date is in past'
ELSE IF (CAST(getdate() AS DATE) = CAST(@DATE AS DATE))
    PRINT 'Selected date is today'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Selected date is in future'
```